# Can I create a report in SQL Reporting Services 2005 to look like a newspaper page

Tags: reporting-services

Our client has requested a report that looks like this:

```
Branch Office: 5445                        Item 3    $8.25    x25
   Order: 123456xx                         Item 4    $10.45   x45
      Item 1    $5.00    x45
      Item 2    $6.40    x40
    ...

Branch Office: 1234
   Order: 4545xx
      Item 1    $7.45    x50
      Item 2    $3.65    x100
```

Please note:  At the end of the page, in column 1, the data should wrap around to column 2 and then column 3.  There would be 3 max columns.  Once the data is full in all 3 columns, there would be a page break.

Is something like this even possible in SQL Reporting Services 2005?

Answer (score 1):

See this page:

**Understanding Pagination in Reporting Services** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677374.aspx

under the subheading, **"Newsletter-Style Columns"**

Comment: That's awesome.  One quick question.  Is there a way to force a page break at the Branch office group.  I tried checking the page break at the beginning & end of the group, but all it does is puts the next group in a new column.  I would like that in a new page.

Comment: If SSRS is counting a column as a page, you can check to see if the page number is odd or even.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not following you.

Comment: If the page number is odd, you're in the left column.  If the page number is even, you're in the right column.  But since I'm not an actual SSRS expert...